# CentOS 7 , OpenVPN Server Radius Plugin

Tags: centos, openvpn, radius

On my new openvpn server install
radius plugin can not read client status.
It worked on previous installation, now all things are the same, but not working.

OpenVPN Server Conf:

```
port 57192 
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
plugin /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.so /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf
duplicate-cn
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh dh.pem
tls-auth tls-auth.key 0
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_Vfvm7OXXaOglE58z.crt
key server_Vfvm7OXXaOglE58z.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

Client:

```
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote ?.?.?.? 57192
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_Vfvm7OXXaOglE58z name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
```

Radius Pluginn:

```
NAS-Identifier=OpenVpn
Service-Type=5
Framed-Protocol=1
NAS-Port-Type=5
NAS-IP-Address=127.0.0.1
OpenVPNConfig=/etc/openvpn/server.conf
subnet=255.255.255.0
overwriteccfiles=true
nonfatalaccounting=false
server
{
acctport=1813
authport=1812
name=?.?.?.?
retry=1
wait=1
sharedsecret=?????
}
```

On server log it shows this:

RADIUS-PLUGIN: BACKGROUND ACCT: No accounting data was found for user01

Comment: Please include your configuration.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: Ok, Here it is my conf files